# Installing Photoshop CS2 on Ubuntu 16.04 through Wine

Tags: ubuntu, photoshop, wine

**System Information:**
Ubuntu 16.04

**Why I need it:**
To automate some of my Photoshop tasks, mainly editing text layers

**Requirement:** I would like to install Photoshop CS2 (I have the installation file and key) on my Ubuntu 16.04 server through Wine.

The problem I have is that my Ubuntu is **non graphical**, so I can't know where to click to continue with the installation and if I manage to install it, edit layers and save/export.

Am I in deep ocean with my wish here or is it possible to pull off in someway?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You can try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Well I was thinking in a programmatic way for an example sending fake keystrokes by command